# winsock compiling error, it cant find the addrinfo structures and some relating functions

Tags: c++, gcc, winsock

I've just started learning winsock through the "Beej's guide to network programming" book. I'm programming under windows and running it through gcc. This is just a start to writing my first server program but it gives me these errors when I try to compile.

```
/* Server */
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
using namespace std;

const int winsockVersion = 2;
#define BACKLOG 10
#define PORT 3000


int main(void){

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(winsockVersion,0),&wsadata) == 0){


        struct addrinfo hints, *res;

        memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        if ( getaddrinfo(NULL,PORT,&hints,&res) == 0 ){
            cout<<"-Call to get addrinfo successful!." << endl;
        }

        cout<<"res af_family" << res->ai_family << endl;
    }




    //clear stuff
    if( WSACleanup() != 0){
        cout<<"-WSACleanup unsuccessful" << endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"-WSACleanup successful" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

these are the errors I'm receiving

```
g++ -o server.exe server.cpp -lws2_32
Process started >>>
server.cpp: In function `int main()':
server.cpp:20: error: aggregate `addrinfo hints' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
server.cpp:25: error: `AI_PASSIVE' was not declared in this scope
server.cpp:27: error: `getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
server.cpp:31: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct addrinfo'
server.cpp:20: error: forward declaration of `struct addrinfo'
server.cpp:54:2: warning: no newline at end of file
<<< Process finished.
```

Shouldn't the structures and functions be defined in either windows.h or winsock.h?.

***SOLUTION***

**EDIT**
to anyone who stumbles on this, add

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
```

at the top of your source if getaddrinfo says that its undeclared.

Comment: hey thanks for that #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
saved me some trouble :)

Comment: I'm on Win7, VS2015, and so far I haven't had to add the #define statement, but DID need to add the #include statement.

My build env may be a little weird since I'm working with a set of old libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`. Remember that before Stack Overflow, [Google](http://www.google.com/#&q=struct+addrinfo+site:msdn.microsoft.com) is your friend for this kind of questions : you will get immediate answers from MSDN !

Comment: thanks for that, But it still doesnt see getaddrinfo for some reason?

Comment: needed to add `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501`, apparently there are different versions of getaddrinfo.

Comment: Let's add that detail into this answer, instead of into the question, hmm?

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says we should `#include <ws2tcpip.h>`, but in `ws2tcpip.h` i found this piece of code:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP)
/**
 * For WIN2K the user includes wspiapi.h for these functions.
 */
void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo (struct addrinfo*);
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
                struct addrinfo**);
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr*,socklen_t,char*,DWORD,
           char*,DWORD,int);
#endif /* (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP) */
```

this means, that `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined lower than `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP`, but when i tried include `wspiapi.h`, i got `"no such file or directory"`. My guess is, this is an fault of MinGW, where different parts of the library have inconsistent versions.
You have to `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` on your own, before including `ws2tcpip.h`

Answer (score 0):

**Beware!** Your includes are wrong. The problem is that `windows.h` already includes `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` then re-defines some structures and functions resulting in huge number of compilation errors. Move the `windows.h` include below the `winsock2.h` include, or just remove the `windows.h` include altogether, `winsock2.h` includes `windows.h`.

Comment: Windows.h includes winsock.h, in order to use winsock2, you need to use the #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN statement. WinSock2 has code that is not compatible with winsock.h. So, in order to use windows.h and WInSock2.h, use the #define.

There is a NOTE halfway down this page that discusses this in better detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 80

void error_die(const char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s failed with error %d\n", s, WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
    "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>"
    "<body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>\r\n";

    char buf[4096];
    int msg_len, addr_len;
    struct sockaddr_in local, client_addr;

    SOCKET sock, msg_sock;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    // Fill in the address structure
    local.sin_family        = AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;
    local.sin_port          = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  //TCP socket

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        error_die("socket()");

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        error_die("bind()");

    if (listen(sock, 5) == SOCKET_ERROR)   // wait for connection
        error_die("listen()");

    printf("Waiting for connection...\n");

    while (1)
    {
        addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        msg_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addr_len);

        if (msg_sock == INVALID_SOCKET || msg_sock == -1)
            error_die("accept()");

        printf("Accepted connection from %s, port %d\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), htons(client_addr.sin_port));

        msg_len = recv(msg_sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        printf("Bytes Received: %d, message: %s from %s\n", msg_len, buf, inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));

        msg_len = send(msg_sock, response, sizeof(response)-1 , 0);

        if (msg_len == SOCKET_ERROR)
            error_die("send()");

        if (!msg_len)
        {
            printf("Client closed connection\n");
            closesocket(msg_sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        closesocket(msg_sock);
    }

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following includes, pragma, and defines...

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

The list of necessary includes for this answer are shown in a Microsoft article:
[Winsock Includes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added `struct` when declaring `sockaddr_in`.

changed:

`sockaddr_in m_sockAddr;`

to

`struct sockaddr_in m_sockAddr;`

also,

`bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&m_sockAddr, sizeof(m_sockAddrLsng ))`

to

`bind(m_sockLsng, (struct sockaddr*)&m_sockAddr, sizeof(m_sockAddr))`