# Winsock server code not compiling with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock

following is the winsock server code from  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

        // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else  {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code with

> gcc -o server server.c -lws_32

```
I get the following error messages.

server.cpp:48:62: error: 'getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
     iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
                                                              ^ server.cpp:59:28: error: 'freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
         freeaddrinfo(result);
                            ^ server.cpp:68:28: error: 'freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
         freeaddrinfo(result);
                            ^ server.cpp:74:24: error: 'freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
     freeaddrinfo(result);
```

It seems to me that winsock API is not compatible with MinGW. Is there any way that I can fix this? I think the problem will be solved by using Visual C++, but I want to do it with MinGW.
                            ^

Comment: it is already included in the code

Comment: Sorry, I missed it, I will delete that comment. Also, can you try using Windows specific APIS -- one that starts with upper case? Also, take a look at [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243027/winsock-compiling-error-it-cant-find-the-addrinfo-structures-and-some-relating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem bt adding

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
```

Comment: What exactly does 0x501 mean in this context?

Comment: It is a hexadecimal number.

Comment: That doesn't tell me what it means. Another way of asking is: why is 0x501 correct instead of 0x502, and what is _WIN32_WINNT used for?

Comment: `0x501` stands for Windows XP. More info on `_WIN32_WINNT` and it's constants can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx